# Set blank row after Unique combination of Column 1 + Column 2 coming from Table in Excel

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

```
enter code here
```

> I want to get unique combination of c1 & c2(which are coming from table) like below and create blank row after unique combination. I tried with hashmap but it is taking lot of time. I want to do it in less time.
>   [image]
>
> ```
> downloadObjects is a List<Object[]> coming from Database
> ```

```
for (Object[] download : downloadObjects) {
    for (Object[] download : downloadObjects) {
    String p1 = (String) download[2];
    String c1 = (String) download[0];
    map1.put(p1, c1);
    if (map2.containsKey(platfrom)) {
        List<Object[]> value = map2.get(platfrom);
        value.add(download);
        map2.put(platfrom, value);
    } else {
        List<Object[]> value = new ArrayList<>();
        value.add(download);
        map2.put(platfrom, value);
    }
} 
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    Row row = null;
    List<Object[]> objects = map2.get(entry.getKey());
    for (Object[] data : objects) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue((String) data[2]);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue((String) data[1]);
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue((String) data[0]);
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue((String) data[3]);
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue((String) data[4]);
        row.createCell(5).setBlank();
        row.createCell(6).setCellValue((String) data[5]);
    }
    row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);
    row.createCell(0).setBlank();
    row.createCell(1).setBlank();
    row.createCell(2).setBlank();
    row.createCell(3).setBlank();
    row.createCell(4).setBlank();
    row.createCell(5).setBlank();
    row.createCell(6).setBlank();
}
```

Comment: Are the objects coming from the database in the correct order? Just missing blank rows?

Comment: @RealSkeptic objects are coming in correct order but it is taking lot of time. I want to increase performance....

Comment: I would usually use a single loop, keeping the previous combination, and adding a blank row every time that the combination changes. But are you sure your performance problem is in the map part? Have you measured how much time the map part takes and how much the cell creation?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am trying to fetch approx. 1,40,000 records with unique combination. it is taking lot of time... like 10 min or more.

Comment: But did you *measure* if the problem is in the map part or the Excel creation map? You have to try profiling your problem to understand where you have performance issue. It could be that the database fetch is the reason. It could be saving the excel file. You have to profile it and find where the problem is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic let me know how to get unique combination of two columns without performance issue

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think problem is map part. as previously i was creating excel with the data coming from table and it was not taking much time but this time i have to get combination.